# Element with left: -9999 makes the view jump

Tags: html, css

I'm try to use this plugin:
https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

In order to make dropbox with a search box in it. If you'll take a look at the "Standard select", when the menu is closed, it have absolute position and left -9999 properties, that makes it "disappear". It works good there, however, in my site when the menu is in -9999, all my view is jump to the left with the menu.

This is how it looks when I put `overflow-x:visible` to `html` (without this I can go back only by refreshing).
[image]

You can see this happen in that test page:
http://rashamkol.com/test/

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a URL or JSFiddle?

Comment: @YanivWainer I create a test page for this: http://rashamkol.com/test/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
.chosen-container .chosen-drop {
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}

.chosen-container.chosen-container-single.chosen-with-drop .chosen-drop {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Heard using `left: -9999` instead of `display: block` is better as it still visible in screen readers. Anyway I use this method for now, but if someone has a better solution it will be great. This problem is really weird.

Answer (score 0):

Add the class `chosen-rtl` to your `select` element, in addition to the `chosen-select` class.

It's in the documentation, under Right to Left Support.
https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/